# Вывести фрейм с формой, отредактировав HTML поле.

Tags: jquery, html, php

Нужен скрипт. Есть страница https://ru-eshop.oriflame.com/iframe/Consultant/OnlineQuickRegistration.aspx нам необходимо вывести её в html документе во фрейме, далее работа с фреймом: поле формы “Номер спонсора” должно быть заблокировано для редактирования и туда должно вписываться значение, которое мы захотим. не могу реализовать на jquery.

Comment: @iseolux, Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Прошу метод. Не понимаю как работать со фреймом.

Answer (score 1):

Тег РНР уберите из вопроса - нету его здесь.

На js на своем домене это можно сделать примерно вот так.
Думаю объект myDOMobject вполне можно скормить jQuery.

```
var myIframeObject = document.getElementById("myFrameId");
var myDOMobject = (myIframeObject.contentWindow.document || myIframeObject.contentDocument);
myDOMobject.body.style.backgroundColor="#0000ff";
```

Но вам это не поможет.
Песочница браузера не даст оперировать DOM-содержимым другой страницы на другом домене.